# How to send with Fast-RTPS big array message (larger then 10 MB)

Tags: c++, ros, data-distribution-service, ros2

I'm trying to send and receive a large message with Fast-Rtps.
I had taken the HelloworldExample code and altered its idl message (i added a char array at different sizes)
the biggest size i manged to send was 8370000.

I already found and added to the init() method this line:
Wparam.qos.m_publishMode.kind = ASYNCHRONOUS_PUBLISH_MODE;
it helped but still i'm stuck at 8MB

```
struct HelloWorld
{
    unsigned long index;
    string message;
    char array[8000000];
};
```

When changing the message to:

```
struct HelloWorld
{
    unsigned long index;
    string message;
    char array[9000000];
};
```

i get :
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: It's statically allocating that block of memory, including the history depth. Do you have enough memory?